# Asyncio subprocess pipes give ValueError when terminating

Tags: python, ssh, pipe, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement an SSH write/read program with async. Here you can find a simplified example, only connecting and disconnecting. However, this is giving an error even in the most simplistic case and I do not understand what is going on or what am I doing wrong. I am running it with PyCharm and Python 3.9 on Windows.

```
import asyncio
import platform


async def connect():
    sshcon = 'ssh -T root@192.168.25.1 -p 22'
    io = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
        sshcon,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE
    )
    print("Connected")
    return io


async def disconnect(io):
    io.kill()
    await io.wait()
    print("Disconnected")


async def main():
    io = await connect()
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await disconnect(io)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsProactorEventLoopPolicy())
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The error says the following:

```
Exception ignored in: <function BaseSubprocessTransport.__del__ at 0x00000237DBAAB040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 126, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_subprocess.py", line 104, in close
    proto.pipe.close()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 751, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000237DBAB3940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 115, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 79, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000237DBAB3940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 115, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 79, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000237DBAB3940>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 115, in __del__
    _warn(f"unclosed transport {self!r}", ResourceWarning, source=self)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 79, in __repr__
    info.append(f'fd={self._sock.fileno()}')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\windows_utils.py", line 102, in fileno
    raise ValueError("I/O operation on closed pipe")
ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe
```

I've tried waiting for the loop's tasks to finish and manually closing the pipes. Different errors but unsuccessful results anyway.

Comment: The code works if I "communicate" something, no need to terminate the process explicitly. Not sure if I understand what is going on but you need to interact somehow with the pipes/process, otherwise it never terminates properly.